# Android Studio Gradle keeps making new unrelated errors when building

Tags: android, gradle

I am at my wits end. I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong when using gradle to build my projects.

I am not fiddling with gradle, all I am doing is press 'Sync project with Gradle Files' and almost every hour of work is met with a new and exciting error message.

This time it's

> "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2"

Which is an entirely new error i have never encountered before, which sprung out of nowhere all of a sudden.

Just at the top of my head, i have had disk write errors, because suddenly my files we're appearantly 'read only' (which gradle never complained about before), and random gradle files become corrupt out of nowhere.

Is gradle really this unstable at it's core? Or am I doing something wrong? Do I really have to update Android Studio every single time?

I am using Android Studio 2.1.1

Also, i have Android Studio and SDK's installed on an External Harddrive, could that be the issue?

Comment: There's likely the actual build problem somewhere earlier in your build output. Also, latest stable Android Studio today is 2.1.3. Personally I've had some workspace-related issues with recent versions of the tooling and they are resolved with "Rebuild Project".

Comment: "which sprung out of nowhere all of a sudden": Hmm, why is this difficult to believe? This may only be the case if there is some hardware problem.

Comment: @Henry what i mean with "sprung out of nowhere all of a sudden", is the error appears to have nothing in relation to what i was currently doing. I've tried multiple times in which there were no problems at all, gradle sync worked fine, i go for a lunch brake, come back and suddenly gradle has a new error i've never seen before. I just right at this moment got a another error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library'.
> Could not expand ZIP 'E:\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7\23.4.0\appcompat-v7-23.4.0.aar'.

Comment: multidexdebug that means multiple index found in different dependencies.. show me your whole gradle code.. (gradle.app level)

Comment: Just got another entirely new error: Error:Could not read path 'E:\Android Projects\TestProject\Kitkat\Test3\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.4.0\res\color'.
> E:\Android Projects\TestProject\Kitkat\Test3\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.4.0\res\color: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

Comment: @SagarChavada I don't have a gradle.app (or don't know where to look)

Comment: in android studio look at the left side of project architecture..  in this you can find Gradle Script, there is  build.gradle(Module:app) open it.

Answer (score 0):

Just click on " invalidate cache and restart " under file menu. I hope it works for you. Good Luck.